# Node.js / Express - Not rendering 503 Page on redirect

Tags: node.js, http, express, routes

I'm trying to add a configuration value that allows us to take down the site temporarily when needed. It works, but for some reason it is not rendering the error page I've defined in my 503 route. I'm seeing "Service Unavailable. Redirecting to /503", but it doesn't ever redirect and doesn't display the page. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Middleware:

```
// Maintenance mode
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (config.globals.maintenanceModeEnabled) {

        // Need this condition to avoid redirect loop
        if (req.url !== '/503') {
           res.redirect(503, '/503');
        } else {
            next();
        }

    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Route:

```
//  Down for maintenance page
router.get('/503', function (req, res) {
    res.status(503).render('common/503', {layout: 'base'});
});
```

Comment: Do you need the return statement before res.redirect? What if you remove it?

Comment: Yeah, it's not needed, but removing it doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Oddly enough, removing the status code param (the one that gets passed to the redirect method) fixes the problem :/

Comment: Hmm interesting. I wonder if it would work with a 301/302, but you fixed the problem so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Interesting indeed. It is still problematic because failing to pass the status code ends up defaulting to a 302.

Comment: I think it's coming from the browser and not Express. Maybe it's just assumed that if service is unavailable, redirecting to another URL under the same domain is pointless? Not sure... I'm probably just going to render directly from the middleware and get rid of the 503 route.